# ClickListener getTapCount() returns 0

Tags: libgdx

I want to detect the double tap on a Container. If it is detected, then i have to remove the Actor associated with it.

This is my first attempt:

```
addListener(new ClickListener() {
    if(getTapCount() == 2) {
        System.out.println("double click detected");
    }
    return true;
});
```

It does not work. The method getTapCount() returns always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here, you're using the listener wrong:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373390/button-clicklistener-is-not-working-in-libgdx-game
(you're not overriding its methods, I suggest looking up some more information about listeners and especially this one). And use this question to make sure you're adding the stage and the actor right and that you're setting the stage as the inputProcessor.

That's the first thing, also, here they have the same problem, but it appears unresolved, although it offers some more information:
http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12501&p=55966

According to the [listener's source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.java), the `clicked` event is triggered after you lift your finger and it also counts the taps in that very moment - if the actual interval fits the set `tapCountInterval`.

So the code should be something like this, given your other code concerning the actor and stage is not wrong:

```
// to what are you adding the listener? and shouldn't you use this method instead?
????.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
    // might need to set the tapCountInterval
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        if( getTapCount() == 2) { // put breakpoint here
            System.out.println("double click detected");
        }
    }; 
});
```

PS: Sharing some more code might clarify the issue aswell. :)

Comment: clicked is the right method to use! Now it works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: But i can't understand why it does not work anymore if i override touchDown, touchUp..

Comment: Look at the source code. :) The clicked method is empty, it's there for you to override it, but when you override the methods that aren't empty, you change what they do. The touchUp method suddenly doesn't count the taps. To make it do what it does by default AND also what you want it to do, you have to call `super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button)` in the overriden `touchUp` method.  But I'd still recommend sticking to `clicked`. (Aaand I hope I'm not confusing Java with something else here...)

Comment: Ok i got it. But does the clicked method detect the touch? Because what i need is to detect both double tap (for Android),and double click (for html).

Comment: Yes it does, that's the point.

Comment: Very cool then :)